# Sybase - Determine date format

Tags: sql, date, format, sybase

I have a field `ISSUEDATE` which is a date field. In AquaDataStudio it shows me the date like this `31.03.2017 00:00:00`

If I run a query like this:
...
and ISSUEDATE between '01.04.2016' and '31.03.2017'

it gives me an error:
*Arithmetic overflow during implicit conversion of VARCHAR value '31.03.2017' to a DATE field*

and it works with :

```
and ISSUEDATE between '2016.04.01' and '2017.03.31'
```

Ok, the format of the date is important. But where can I find out which format is actually used behind the scene?

Sybase version:
Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.5/EBF 19902 SMP ESD#5.1/P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux/asear155/2594/64-bit/FBO/Wed Jun  6 01:20:27 2012

Comment: Behind the scenes, likely neither format is being used.  Dates are usually stored in an RDBMS as seconds since the epoch.  Just know that `yyyy-mm-dd` and similar formats is what is accepted as a date literal.

Comment: Ok, and what about datetime, in which format do I have to query against a datetime field? Because CREATEDATE in ('2016.04.29 12:27:43') doesn't seem to work. But that's exactly the date and time shown in the db

Answer (score 1):

Run this command first:

set dateformat dmy

And then re-run your query. 
By default, the day-month-year order is 'mdy' which won't work with your date format.